# Is there a way to make filtered tasks show up as originally created?

Tags: filter, task-list

[image: Screenshot of Task List Filtered View]

I am using SharePoint 2013. My question is about the filter view for task list items.

I originally created the task items as follows

1. Job Vacancies
2. Resume Review
3. Interviews
4. Job Offers

However, after I work with the filter I can't seem to find out how to put them in original order again. Is there a way?

And why isn't the A on Top and Z on Top working?

I have more to ask about this filter but I think I'm getting a hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter in that image is for the task 'completed' status. Only 'Yes' or 'No' allowed. I believe you want to sort than filter. If so, you can use 'ID' column in the sort order of any view which likely to give you the tasks in the order you created them.